# is it okay to start a paragraph with Due to?

Tags: grammaticality, orthography

Due to the severe foot injury, I was recommended to stay on bed rest for three months and also attend physical therapy to heal completely

Comment: [due to a ] You might want to post at ELL instead of here.

Comment: It depends who you ask, but [some people](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-due-to-since-and-as) have an issue with that usage. If it's a formal context, I would consider changing it. Otherwise, your meaning is nonetheless perfectly clear.

Comment: Yes of course you can.

Comment: I fail to see why anyone would think this is not okay, and I fail to see how you would rephrase it without changing the meaning. How *would* you rephrase it without changing the meaning? You cannot.

Comment: The argument (which I'm not espousing, just pointing out) is that *due* is an adjective, not a preposition, and needs to have something to modify. The alternative, according to such purists, would be to use a prepositional phrase ("because of" or "on account of"), or modify the sentence such that there is a noun to modify (e.g. "The recommendation that I stay on bed rest was due to the severe foot injury"). Despite all that, it's widely accepted that "due to" is treated as a prepositional phrase and the sentence as given would be just fine in the eyes of most people.